# How to sync table data of Navision (Dynamics NAV) to AWS Microsoft SQL Server and vice versa

Tags: sql-server, navision, dynamics-nav

Suddenly one requirement came that we need to sync our SQL Server table from  navision server and vice versa (need to handle update, delete, insert also)

Can someone help me to achieve this?

I am using SQL Server developer and I'm new to Navision

Comment: Please be more specific on your task and specify Nav version.

Comment: @Mak Sim, nav version 2013 R2

Comment: What about being more specific on your task?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you could use [External table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/external-tables) to connect to AWS server. Depends on task really. In other cases you could use web services to connect on application level rather than on database level.